# ajax is not working in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#designation').change(function () {
        var opt=this.value;
       // var login_url = '{{ url("ajax_crud") }}';
        alert(opt);
        $.ajax({
           //alert(opt);

           type: "post",
           url:'ajax_type' ,
           data: {option:opt},
           success: function(data){
               alert('hiii');
               //$("#div_dprtmnt").html(data);
               //document.getElementById("department").innerHTML=data;
           }
        });
    });

    });
```

this is my view page.jquery is working.but inside the ajax alert is not working.how to use $.ajax in laravel.please help me

Comment: What is not working? What error do you get? What did you try? If you add some `console.log()` or `alert()`in your function, where start the problem?

Comment: inside $.ajax ,i try to alert opt value.but its not working....

Comment: actually how to check ajax is working or not in laravel

Comment: What does your console log says? You can see console log by using inspect element.

Comment: $.ajax({
                console.log(); Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: If you do a `console.log(opt)` before the `$.ajax` what do you get? If you want the value, is it not `var opt = $(this).val()` you should use to get the value? Then in your `$.ajax` call your url is `ajax_type`, what is it? I don't know Laraval but with Symfony you can use `url : '{{ path('your_route_name') }}'` if you use Twig for example, but you need to have this JS code inside your template and not in a `file.js`

Comment: thank you bro...let me check

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue with your CSRF token.  Ensure you are attaching a token on each request to protect from forgery.  You can do all this like this in ajax like this:

```
(document).ready(function () {
    $('#designation').change(function () {
        var opt = this.value;
        $.ajax({
           _token: "{{ csrf_field() }}",
           type: "post",
           url: "ajax_type",
           data: {
               option: opt
           },
           success: function(data){
               alert('hiii');
           }
        });
    });
});
```